# How to position padded image?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, imagesharp

I can create an image of an arbitrary size using this code:

```
using var image = original.Clone(context =>
    context.Pad(width, height, Color.White)
);
```

However, this places the original image in the center of the new image.  Is there a way to specify the location (e.g., using AnchorPositionMode)?  I'd like the original image in the bottom right corner of the new image.

Answer (score 0):

[`Pad`](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing.PadExtensions.html) as described in the docs is designed for evenly padding an image to fit the new dimensions.

You can combine `Resize` with [`ResizOptions`](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing.ResizeOptions.html) to position padding but if you require fine grained control use [`DrawImage`](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing.DrawImageExtensions.html).